# How to declare default route in Angular2 CLI?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-cli

I made a small project using angular CLI but i don't know how to declare default route in CLI. I used '/' for parent component and it works but if i use '/' for child component it does not work.

My **parent.component.ts** is:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: LoginComponent },
])
```

**parent.component.html** is:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Login']"></a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**child.component.ts** is:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/', component: DashboardComponent},
])
```

**child.component.html** is:

```
<li class="treeview">
    <a [routerLink]="['']">Dashboard</a>
</li>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This method works with parent and child both but i want a route with another path e.g. "/dashboard" as default.
Is there any way to define default route in child component.

Comment: Paths in routes should not have a leading `/` in the new alpha.7 router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to try this: -

```
export const HomeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', terminal: true},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, terminal: true }
];
```

PS:- Not Tested
[Credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041184/5043867)

## update

you also can try defining your route twice like this:-

```
{ path: '/', component: HomeComponent}
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
```

by doing so there is default as well as named router for same component.

hope may help you.

Comment: I updated my answer. `terminal: true` is not necessary for the `home` route. Thanks for the credit :)

Answer (score 1):

Put this option in your route config

```
{ ...,  terminal: true}
```

Comment: no,  I think it tells the router that it doesn't need to check for other matching routes if this one matches.